# redirect .php to non php in current directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem in .htaccess which I honestly don't have any idea how to code this but I have this code came from here in this site

```
#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

now I just want to redirect the .php files into non php files on the same page

for example I have www.examplesite.com/dir1/dir2/file.php then it will redirect me in www.examplesite.com/dir1/dir2/file . How can I do that? I have so many folders in the directory tho. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
#remove the .php extention for root dir only 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php
```